# Remove columns from a dataframe based on number of rows with valid values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(gene = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                value1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 1),
                value2 = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                value3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1))
```

I would like to keep all those columns (plus the first, gene) with more than or equal to atleast 2 valid values (i.e., not NA). How do I do this?

I am thinking something like this ...

```
df1 = df %>% select_if(function(.) ...)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `sum` the non-NA elements and create a logical condition to `select` the columns of interest

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
          select_if(~ sum(!is.na(.)) > 2)
df1
#   gene value2
#1    a     NA
#2    b      1
#3    c      2
#4    d      3
#5    e      4
```

Or another option is `keep`

```
library(purrr)
keep(df, ~ sum(!is.na(.x)) > 2)
```

Or create the condition based on the number of rows

```
df %>%
   select_if(~ mean(!is.na(.)) > 0.5)
```

---

Or use `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) sum(!is.na(x)) > 2, df)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `colSums` in base R to count the non-NA value per column

```
df[colSums(!is.na(df)) > 2]

#  gene value2
#1    a     NA
#2    b      1
#3    c      2
#4    d      3
#5    e      4
```

Or using `apply`

```
df[apply(!is.na(df), 2, sum) > 2]
```